# Is it possible to build custom GUI like this in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I made this in Photoshop and I plan to use it for my file sharing application:

[image: Screenshot]

I was wondering if it was possible to create GUI for my application that is gonna have this look and feel.

If I can't build it only by using eclipse or NetBeans, are there any other tools that could help me?

Comment: You should probably just do it in the regular look-and-feel first, then worry about the snazzy looks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is not only possible but quite easy, you don't have to go all the way to create a custom Look and Feel.

This is what I've made in 20 minutes:

[image: 20mins]

There is a lot of information on the web on how to customize the components without having to create a whole new L&F.

Understanding the [Swing Architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/) helps a lot.

Just in case you haven't read it the [Swing Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/) is here.

Finally you'll need the doc: [Java doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html)

Comment: JButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()); and JButton.setOpaque(true); are your friends.

Answer (score 33):

Oh dear, no-no-no! If you want your users' eyes to bleed, then go for it. Otherwise, follow whatever UI guidelines are appropriate for your platform.

To answer your question: this is certainly doable in any modern windowing system.

Here's what generally happens when programmers design UIs:

[image: wGetGUI]
<sub>(source: [jensroesner.de](http://www.jensroesner.de/wgetgui/wgetgui.png))</sub>

[image: Bulk Rename Utility]
<sub>(source: [bulkrenameutility.co.uk](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Screenshots.php))</sub>

Comment: That looks like usual GUI with general GUI components. 
I want something to create custom components for example like those in the picture I added. Is there any software for that sort of thing?

Comment: I understand what you all wanted to say. Programmers ARE NOT designers. That's a general fact :)

Comment: This actually looks better than most UIs I've seen here.  I'm not kidding.

Comment: I see a "Simple" tab pretty prominently there.  I bet it has fewer tweakable options.  It should probably be the default open tab for first-time use, but other than that...looks fine to me.

Comment: Gorgeous! :D It wouldn't be so funny, if it wasn't so sad.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable UI. Everything is completely understandable.

Answer (score 9):

You can and even you can change it dynamically - see [Look-n-Feel feature](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/sce/index.html) of swing

Answer (score 7):

It's possible.  But for most Java developers, it would require suppressing the gag reflex at such an ugly interface.

Here's a [Java interface](http://gallery.xcski.com/index.php/misc-pics/screenshots/choosedate) I wrote using no tools other than vi.  I didn't design it, I just took the artists design, held my nose, and implemented it.

As for specifics, I'd suggest doing as much of the look and feel through the pluggable look and feel in Swing.  Also, use LayoutManagers rather than making things constant sizes in constant locations, so that things can grow and shrink to different screen resolutions and also so that if you translate things you don't end up having to resize all your text labels and then shuffling everything else around.

Comment: +1 OK, nice. Diet Coke all over my keyboard now. *shakes fist*

Comment: If you want to ask a specific question, ask a specific question.  Otherwise don't whinge that I answered your "Is it possible" question.

Comment: OKAY, let me be precise. Which program or tools should I use for making my custom GUI?

Comment: That one seems rather complicated. Thanks for the example.

Comment: The only program or tool I would suggest is a good editor, and a web browser for looking up stuff.  That's all I ever used.

Answer (score 4):

Creating new LaF is too much. Since all your JButtons are different, just use `JButton.setIcon()` and `JButton.setPressedIcon()` and use your images. The rest is loading background and using strange fonts. Use [`Font.createFont()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) to load custom fonts. You'll probably have to draw your own JProgressbar. Override `JProgressBar.paintComponent(Graphics g)` and draw your own image.

Answer (score 3):

Well thats very much possible, although alot of Java Swing developers might not agree with the UI in the image. perhaps rightly so.

Although to make it very possible try looking at `JWindow`, `JTable`, `ImageIcon`, `Dimension`, `JProgressBar`.
You will also need ample of understanding for Java Layouts, and Events such as `MouseEvents`, `ActionEvents`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does help me.
I cover all the basics concerning GUI, but this is something that is still out of my league.

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible using [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Check out the [NetBeans GUI Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html)

Comment: I know how to use Swing, just didn't know all the options. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a lot of custom JComponents. Other than that, possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend

[MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

for laying out components, it's very easy to grasp and is also way more powerful than the standard layout managers (and it's got a nice debugging mode, too).

Comment: "layouting"?? Are there any "lays" in the closet... perhaps, "laying out components"?

Answer (score 1):

***I have to disagree with you!*** Actually you **can** use **NetBeans** to create such a **GUI**.
It is *easy* too, you have a lot of options to work with! The ones I personally use are:

***1)*** Create graphics with a *painting software*, and set it as **Icon** to the component. I use for the designing process **InkScape**, but *any software* should do the trick. You have to be preatty careful in this process, becouse you **can't resize images** in NetBeans (well, I never tried).

***2)*** extend the **UI** class *(Example: public class CustomButtonUI extend BasicButtonUI)*, and override the method **paint**, then use the function setUI (componentName.setUI(new CustomButtonUI);)

*This is an example code:*

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;

/**
 *
 * @author Ionut Cicio
 */
public class CustomButton extends BasicButtonUI{

    int borderThickness, edgeRoundness;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(c.getBackground());

        borderThickness = 2;
        edgeRoundness = 20;

        g2.setColor(c.getForeground());
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), edgeRoundness+5, edgeRoundness+5);
        g2.drawRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), edgeRoundness+5, edgeRoundness+5);
        //g2.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
        //g2.drawRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());

        g2.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g2.fillRoundRect(borderThickness, borderThickness, c.getWidth()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), c.getHeight()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), edgeRoundness, edgeRoundness);
        g2.drawRoundRect(borderThickness, borderThickness, c.getWidth()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), c.getHeight()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), edgeRoundness, edgeRoundness);

        super.paint(g, c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintFocus(Graphics g, AbstractButton b, Rectangle viewRect, Rectangle textRect, Rectangle iconRect) {

    }
}
```

It always happens to use ***both methods together***, and it gives you a really big benefit whe working on ***animations***!

For some kinds of **UI**'s as **BasicTextFieldUI**, understanding how painting works is preatty tricky, but still understandable.