# UI library for VB.net Desktop Applications

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

Are there any libraries available that can help to change the **look-and-feel** of ***Desktop Applications made using VB.net 2008***? Here is a snapshot of an application that runs on **Windows 7**:

[image]

I think its made using the .net framework, but how can it be styled like this?

**PS** - Even if its not built using .net framework, then please let me know which language supports the UI customization on windows platform.

**NOTE** - As everyone is suggesting me to go with WPF or SWING using JAVA, I still want to know if its possible in VB.net WinForms or not.

Comment: I am quite not accustomed with XAML and WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theme handlers (Use standard controls and the handler takes care of the visual UI):

**Open source**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FancyNetForms.aspx
[image: FancyNetForms]

**Closed source**
http://www.appface.com/  ($ 149 USD) (Skin your app with 2 lines of code)
[image: appface]

Special controls that has built in theaming:
ComponentOne:
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWinForms/

Infragistics:
http://www.infragistics.com/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this specific window was styled, but there are many posibilities:

Maybe was made in WPF. Microsoft WPF are available since VS2008 and Framework 3.0 and it allow to make a complete look and feel customization for every control that you use.

Maybe It was made in winforms using a custom control set. For example, DevExpress has a set of 60 free controls that comes with some predefined look and allow creating your own skin. ([60 Free Controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/))

Maybe It just was made in Java with Swing (look this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049015/is-it-possible-to-build-custom-gui-like-this-in-java))